# Sed remove MAC address indicated by lines including keywords

Tags: sed, mac-address

I'm working on obfuscating MAC address in a file in lines including specific characters. However, I only want to remove it in the lines indicated by an "event" keyword. The hard thing for me is that there will will be random length of keywords (including numbers and letters) in between "even" keyword and the MAC address. 
So I'm substituting:

```
[random length combinations of words, numbers, potentially punctuation or space] "event" [random length combinations of words, numbers, potentially punctuation or space] "xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx" [random length combinations of words, numbers, potentially punctuation, nothing at all or space]
```

to a "x"
I only know how to obfuscate the MAC address:

```
sed -E 's/'([[:xdigit:]]{2}:){5}[[:xdigit:]]{2}')/ x /g'
```

But I don't know how to modify it to obfuscate it for the specific lines. For example, I have a file input.txt:

```
[INFO] device 1 event - client connected with aa:bb:8a:de:8e:23
[ERROR] device 2 event - routing data to gg:7a:e3:89:2f:2f failed
[LOG] device 3 connected 
[INFO] connected to 2 devices. event: aa:bb:8a:de:8e:23 success!
```

the output should be:

```
[INFO] device 1 event - client connected with x
[ERROR] device 2 event - routing data to x failed
[LOG] device 3 connected 
[INFO] connected to 2 devices. event: x success!
```

Comment: A few questions. Can we always assume that the word `event` will always appear before the MAC address? Will there ever be more than one MAC address on one line? (We only care about those lines that also have the word `event` in them.) Does `event` have to be a full word, or just a subtring, as in `eventful` for example? (I assume it must be a full word, but please confirm). And, you want the MAC address replaced simply with `x`, not `xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx`?

Comment: Note a mistake in your example: `g` is not a hex digit. So `gg:7a:...` will not be masked (in your `[ERROR]` row). Not sure if that was just a mistake on your part when you typed the example, or if you used `g` on purpose to show a possible mistake in the inputs. If that were to happen, how should it be handled?

Comment: @mathguy Yes we can always assume that the `event` is before the MAC address. As far as I know there won't be two MAC address at the same time. `event` has to be a full word not a sub string. And yes, I would like to replace the address with a single `x`, not the full address. And sorry about the `g` I made an example in hurry. In the real file, the MAC address will be all hex. And if there are other strings happen to have this format and not a hex number `xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx` we will ignore it. And thank you for the attention to detail

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one possible `sed` solution - which allows `event` to appear anywhere on the line, it must be a complete word (not part of a longer word, like `eventful`), and there may be multiple MAC addresses on a line - which all must be masked if the word `event` is present on the same line. I also use `xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx` as the mask, but you can replace that easily.

I created the following input file for testing:

```
$ cat mac.input

[INFO] device 1 event - client connected with aa:bb:8a:de:8e:23
[ERROR] device 2 event - routing data to gg:7a:e3:89:2f:2f failed
[LOG] device 3 connected 
[INFO] connected to 2 devices. event: aa:bb:8a:de:8e:23 success!
[LINE] this was an eventful evening 22:33:22:33:22:33
[TWO MAC ADDRESSES] aa:bb:aa:33:dd:1f is event 99:33:00:23:43:83 good
```

As I mentioned already, the "address" on the second line will not be masked (even though the word `event` is present) because the address is not a valid MAC address to begin with - `g` is not a hex digit. The address on the `[LINE]` line will not be masked, because the word `event` by itself is not present (even though `eventful` is). On the last line there are two MAC addresses, and I have both masked - even the one that appears **before** the word event. (I asked you in a Comment to clarify if such situations are possible, and if they are, how they must be handled; here I just made a random choice to show what is possible.)

So, here's the `sed` command and its output:

```
$ sed -E '/\bevent\b/
>   s/([[:xdigit:]]{2}:){5}[[:xdigit:]]{2}/xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx/g' mac.input 

[INFO] device 1 event - client connected with xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
[ERROR] device 2 event - routing data to gg:7a:e3:89:2f:2f failed
[LOG] device 3 connected 
[INFO] connected to 2 devices. event: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx success!
[LINE] this was an eventful evening 22:33:22:33:22:33
[TWO MAC ADDRESSES] xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx is event xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx good
```

Comment: thank you very much! This is a very well rounded solution!

Comment: Hi, I have one follow up question. Now due to some situation, I need to store all cli command in a string format. So when I put this command in a string I converted it into 
`sed -E '/\\bevent\\b/s/([[:xdigit:]]{2}:){5}[[:xdigit:]]{2}/xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx/g' ` but it does not work now. So could you let me know how I can convert his command into a string format please?

Comment: @ImTrying - I'm not sure what kind of string you are trying to convert to. Specifically, why do you need to double the back-slashes? Who else is interpreting them first? (I expect that a possible answer is "no one", so you don't need to do that in the first place.) Did you try to save the string EXACTLY as is? And another question: I thought I asked, and you answered that you really did want to replace with `xxx` - but now I see you are using `xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx`. Did you change your mind?

Comment: so I have: 
`int boolInt = -1; boolInt = snprintf(cmd, 256, "%s | sed -E '/\bevent\b/s/([[:xdigit:]]{2}:){5}[[:xdigit:]]{2}/ * /g' | gzip -c | base64 > \"%s\"", infoFile, file); `

sorry I'm not so sure what you mean by save the string as it is. I tried to do a simple experiment to see that out put of print this command directly: 

`printf("sed -E '/\bevent\b/s/([[:xdigit:]]{2}:){5}[[:xdigit:]]{2}/xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx/g'")`
 has shown me: 
`sed -E '/event/s/([[:xdigit:]]{2}:){5}[[:xdigit:]]{2}/xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx/g'`

Comment: but `printf("sed -E '/\\bevent\\b/s/([[:xdigit:]]{2}:){5}[[:xdigit:]]{2}/xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx/g'")` has shown me: `sed -E '/\bevent\b/s/([[:xdigit:]]{2}:){5}[[:xdigit:]]{2}/xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx/g'` so i assumed using the latter is the correct way